# How to take screenshot on Android when app disables it?

Tags: android, screenshot, user-experience

I'm working on a UX analysis of an existing Android app and I need to take screenshots of every screen as I'm using the app. Once I log in, I'm no longer able to take screenshots. (It was obviously disabled for privacy). Is there a way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: So are you asking us a way around piracy? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can project your phone screen to your PC and then take a screenshot on your PC.

To project your android screen on to your PC, you can use an app like [Vysor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vysor/gidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm).

Comment: this method doest actually work for videos may be for just screenshots or may be not, they might have fixed it by now thats the reason i got black screen, even when its cast the screen will be black.

Answer (score 0):

Root your phone and install this XPosed module: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.prashantwosti.bypassflagsecure

Comment: I apparently can't root my phone. I'm using an AT&T Moto-X running 4.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to download the Android Developer Kit. The Android Device Monitor has a button for taking screen grabs of the device that is being monitored via USB. You'll need to enable developer mode and make sure the phone can be debugged via USB.

If you have access to an Android developer, they'll be set up to do this already.

Comment: Thanks! Once I download it, enable developer mode, and enable usb debugging, how do I get to the Device Monitor? I just read "enter the following command from the SDK tools/ directory" but I can't find that. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monitor.html

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is an app that I downloaded from the play store - not one I've developed.

Comment: Well you can still use the Android Studio - Device Monitor to take screen shots.

Comment: Nope, I tried taking a screenshot with Android Studio - Device monitor and it doesn't work if the app itself has disabled taking screenshots.